# How to use printf "%.2f\n" to change number of decimals for all columns in linux

Tags: linux

I have a data big data file and I want to change number of decimals for all numbers in Linux terminal. For example 1 to 1.00  and  0.5 to 0.50

I could do it for just one column with

```
awk '{printf("%.2f\n",$1)}' file > file2
```

How can I do it for all columns???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over all the columns:

```
awk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) $i = sprintf("%.2f", $i);}1' file1 > file2
```